# Swagger 2 springfox @ApiModel subtype not working

Tags: swagger, springfox

I am using **swagger2** annotations in **spring boot**.I am using springfox-**swagger2 version 2.2.2** .

The "example" property in `@ApiModelProperty` annotation is not getting recognised.

**@ApiModelProperty(name="empName", example="someName")**

In swagger.json it is displayed as "`empName":"string`" instead of "`empName":"someName`".

Also the "subtypes" property in `@ApiModel` is not recognised.

Please help!

Comment: support for subtypes introduced in 2.9.0
see here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this feature has been introduced in version `2.3.0` of this library.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to 2.3.0 resolved the example field problem. The subtype in !=@ApiModel still does not work!